# How to deploy an artifact from Nexus to Subversion?

Tags: svn, jenkins, nexus

I am trying to use maven+svn+jenkins+nexus to build a fast develop environment.

I could use jenkins to check out source code from svn and build. After that I deploy the `my_pro.jar` generated by the source code to the nexus.

Now I need to commit `my_pro.jar` to the SVN, and restart the server.
I learn that I could use post-build task plugin to run a script, so that I could download the jar from the nexus with curl command. How to commit `my_pro.jar` to svn by script?

Comment: You shouldn't be committing jar files or other artifacts to your artifact repository manager (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva, etc). Subversion is a place to store your sources, not your binaries.

Comment: @carlspring thanks for your common, because the production environment using jars to provide the service, so i have to fetch the jar from the nexus to deploy to the SVN.

Comment: Well, then you should produce a maven assembly of some sort which contains these jars. It is extremely poor practice to keep your jars under Version Control (svn, git, etc...).